# Squaring signal for amplitude demodulation

Tags: frequency-spectrum, demodulation

I read the following [here](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/dsp/examples/envelope-detection.html). Can someone explain/elaborate on this?

> Squaring the signal effectively demodulates the input by using itself
>   as its own carrier wave. This means that half the energy of the signal
>   is pushed up to higher frequencies and half is shifted down toward DC

I didn't find any good source giving more information or examples of this.

Comment: Please see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_detector). It's a standard technique for [amp.Demod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detector_(radio)).

Answer (score 2):

If $m(t)$ is the message signal with $|m(t)|<1$, the AM signal can be written as

$$s(t)=(1+m(t))\cos(\omega_ct)\tag{1}$$

where $\omega_c$ is the carrier frequency in radians per second. Squaring $s(t)$ gives

$$s^2(t)=(1+m(t))^2\cos^2(\omega_ct)=(1+m(t))^2\frac12(1+\cos(2\omega_ct))\tag{2}$$

Low pass filtering $(2)$ gives

$$x(t)=\frac12(1+m(t))^2\tag{3}$$

from which the message $m(t)$ can be retrieved:

$$m(t)=\sqrt{2x(t)}-1\tag{4}$$

Comment: @Ojtwist: If this answer is helpful, please accept it by clicking on the check mark to its left. Otherwise, you can leave a comment asking for clarification.